# How can I use markdown package (For text with bullet point) inside the ListView Widget? Nothing show when use it inside ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget, flutter-packages

This is my code. I want to use the [MarkDown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown#-readme-tab-) widget inside the ListView widget. But when I using nothing to show on the page. Without ListView/Column it working properly. But, I need to use it inside the ListView Widget. I want something like the below picture. Thank You.

```
 class SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccountState createState() => _SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccountState();
}

    class _SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccountState extends State<SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccount> {
  final testData = ["Flutter", "Dart", "Mobile Application", "Andriod Studio"];

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final _markDownData = testData.map((x) => "- $x\n").reduce((x,
        y) => "$x$y");

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Delete my account'),
      ),
    body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 15.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.error,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Deleting your account will:',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Markdown(
            data: _markDownData,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `Markdown` with `Container` and provide `height` because you use `ListView`
code snippet

```
Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Markdown(
              data: _markDownData,
            ),
          ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

class SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccountState createState() =>
      _SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccountState();
}

class _SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccountState
    extends State<SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccount> {
  final testData = ["Flutter", "Dart", "Mobile Application", "Andriod Studio"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _markDownData =
        testData.map((x) => "- $x\n").reduce((x, y) => "$x$y");

    print(_markDownData);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Delete my account'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 15.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.error,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Deleting your account will:',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Markdown(
              data: _markDownData,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SettingsAccountDeleteMyAccount(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, chunhunghan. it's working properly in my application.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `Markdown` widget with a `MarkdownBody` widget. According to the [`flutter_markdown`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown#-readme-tab-) docs:

> If you do not want the padding or scrolling [**this is the one you want to stop**] behavior, use the MarkdownBody instead:

```dart
MarkdownBody(data: markdownSource);
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem. I had a Markdown widget inside a scrollable ListView, and I could not scroll down the Markdown. Replacing it by MarkdownBody made it not scrollable anymore, to be able to use the ListView scroller.

Comment: Yes, you'll want to wrap your `MarkdownBody` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` - that'll make it scroll by itself, or you could put it inside a `ListView`, if you have multiple things you need to scroll.